# Как в Yii2 задать несколько сообщений об ошибках валидации?

Tags: php, yii2, валидация

Например, я хочу чтобы когда «и неверное число, и лимит в 10 человек» — появлялись разные сообщения об ошибках валидации; так как одно появляется на русском, а второе на английском.

Примерно вот что я хочу:

```
[
  ['peop_number'],
  'integer',
  'message' => 'Должно быть числом',
  'max' => 10,
  'message'=>'Не может превышать 10 человек',
],
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`message`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-validator.html#$message-detail) — это общее сообщение об ошибке валидатора.

---

У многих валидаторов, помимо `message`, есть дополнительные «сообщения об ошибках», которые описывают ошибку более точно. В частности, у валидатора [`integer`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-numbervalidator.html) есть свойство [`tooBig`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-numbervalidator.html#$tooBig-detail), которое описывает ошибку, возникшую в случае невалидного значения свойства `max`.

---

Ваши правила должны выглядеть так:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [
            'peop_number',
            'integer',
            'message' => 'Должно быть числом',
            'max' => 10,
            'tooBig' => 'Не может превышать {max} человек',
        ],
    ];
}
```

Где, `{max}` — это «placeholder», который будет автоматически заменён на значение свойства `max`.

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте так:

```
public function rules()
{
  return [
    ['peop_number', 'integer', 'message'=>'Должно быть числом'],
    ['peop_number', 'validateMaxValue'],
  ];
}

public function validateMaxValue()
{
  if ($this->peop_number > 10) {
    $this->addError('peop_number', 'Не может превышать 10 человек');
  }
}
```

Comment: Рабочий вариант, спасибо. Но ниже, более точный и лаконичный способ, думаю и более стандартный.

Comment: @dimabuhayov, ага, другой вариант в данной ситуации будет более правильным, но этот тоже пригодится, на случай нестандартной валидации :)

Answer (score 0):

При дампе модели ключи сообщений ошибок можно посмотреть:

```
object(yii\validators\StringValidator)#177 (20) {
    ...
    ["message"]=>
    string(70) "Значение «{attribute}» должно быть строкой."
    ["tooShort"]=>
    NULL
    ["tooLong"]=>
    NULL
    ["notEqual"]=>
    string(183) "Значение «{attribute}» должно содержать {length, number} {length, plural, one{символ} few{символа} many{символов} other{символа}}."
    ...
  }
```